# dump only rows that meet a specific criteria like limit 1000

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I'm running this : mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p database_name table_name --where="1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1000" > few_rows_dump.sql

Error: mysql: unknown variable 'where=1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1000'

Comment: Is your variable name: where=1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1000 ?

Comment: What specifically is supposed to meet your "criteria" of "limit 1000"? Your '--where="1 ORDER BY ... "  ' is not valid SQL .